# How can I disable the search for applications in software center when I press windows key and start typing?

Tags: 17.10

How can I disable the search for applications in software center when I press windows key and start typing? I just want to find installed applications.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open *Settings*.
2. Go to the "*Search*" section.
3. Toggle off "*Software*".
   [image]
4. Reboot.